# Not able to get the values of producer.override.* while creating a Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

In order to get the higher throughput with the CSVSourceConnector I am overriding the producer configuration using producer.override.* while creating the connector. But I'm not able to see any difference and also in the code values are not reflecting, like for batch.size it's showing the default one only.

Curl Command to create the connector :

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Accept:application/json" \
    -H  "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/CsvSchemaSpoolDir5.6/config     \
    -d '{
    "connector.class": "com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector",
    "name": "CsvSchemaSpoolDir5.6",
    "topic": "topicPrefix1.7",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "cleanup.policy": "MOVEBYDATE",
    "schema.generation.enabled": "true",
    "input.path": "/opt/csv-source-connector-poc/testdata/singleTopicMultipleCSVFiles",
    "error.path": "/opt/csv-source-connector-poc/error",
    "finished.path": "/opt/csv-source-connector-poc/finished",
    "input.file.pattern": "^.*csv$",
    "error.max.count": "5",
    "fetching.schema.registry.data": "true",
    "schema.registry.url": "https://psrc-znpo0.ap-southeast-2.aws.confluent.cloud",
    "multiple.csv.files.to.single.topic": "true",
    "basic.auth.user.info": "sdfsdfs:sdfsdfsdfsdfds",
    "file.topic.mapping.path": "/opt/csv-source-connector-poc/fileTopicMapping",
    "producer.override.batch.size": "200",
    "producer.override.linger.ms": "50",
    "producer.override.compression.type": "lz4",
    "producer.override.acks": "1"**
}'
```

Code logs :

`SpoolDirCsvSourceTask.process() : this.config.batchSize : 50`

I tried to use the updated producer.override.* values but it seems it's not working.  Apart from the Curl Command, which place needs to be updated to get these values?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running a version of Connect that supports those options; they were only added after 2.3.0 release, according to the docs

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect

In the `connect-distributed.properties`, make sure you have `connector.client.config.override.policy=All`, as well.

Comment: Thanks Jordan for the response !! I did changes as per your suggestions and tested but still not getting the expected result.  Here sharing all the details with you, pls see if you can see anything is missing.  Confluent version is  : confluent-7.2.0
Added property in connect-distributed.properties  : connector.client.config.override.policy=All
Testing around 5 Million records (file size - 103 MB )
Row is like : 1,1.2,test206.1,true
Confluent version is  : confluent-7.2.0
Row is like : 1,1.2,test206.1,true

Comment: Continuing Comments : Following are the configuration used using producer.override. 3 times tested with different batch.size, surprisingly When reducing the batch.size getting better throughput.
batch.size - 1000 - 30 min
batch.size - 50 - 19 min
batch.size - 10 - 9 min
Below all other configurations, which are same for all 3 scenarios
linger.ms - 100000
compression.type - lz4
acks - 0
buffer.memory - 4294967296
request.timeout.ms - 300000
message.max.bytes - 20971520
I need to process very heavy files, approx 1 GB size and that is not possible without having good throughput, thanks

Comment: I'm having a difficult time reading your comment. Edit your question instead. Besides, my answer is only to address the issue of overriding the defaults. I have no suggestions on throughput, and you'll need to do your own benchmarking on your own systems... In my experience, Kafka shouldn't be used for handling plaintext "file transfers", anyway